# Adding bootstrap to webpack. Why second way don't work

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4

There is the only way how it works for me

in js scrypts add:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery = $;
global.$ = $;

import Popper from 'popper.js'
global.Popper = Popper

import 'bootstrap'

// there $.fn defined anyway
// and in chrome console too (in first way)
```

Second way (don't works):

```
// ! comment this strings
// import $ from 'jquery';
// global.jQuery = $;
// global.$ = $;
// after bootstrap importing add

 console.log($.fn) // Object, defined   
 // past it in console after execution - it will undefined

// add in config
plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
        {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'global.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'global.$': 'jquery',
        },
     ),
...
```

But if to do lower way, I don't know why, at the console on scrypt ended, $.fn undefined. It looks like other examplar of $ used in console and in webpack build.
Can somebody explain this?

there is this [build repo](https://github.com/4t4nner/webpack-4-build) to clone

Comment: You commented out the definition of `$` and you are surprised to see complaints about it not being defined?

Comment: webpack.ProvidePlugin defines $ and it works. $.fn - don't. And $.fn defined after importing bootstrap. Why it not defined later?